# Jquery Mobile pageshow function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-widgets

I am building a webapp using the jqm framework and I have been attempting to use the `pageshow` function when including a jQuery widget, k3dcarousel. On the page in question, I have my script underneath the `data-role="page"` div,

```
$("#page-about").live(
    "pageshow",
    function (event) {
        $('#k3dCarousel_portrait').k3dCarousel();
    }
);
```

It seems that I need to click on my link twice to get the JS function to load, which would make me think I am using this function wrong. Also, If I don't use the 
`$("#page-about").die();`
function underneath the `pageshow` function, the script will get loaded multiple times if I click back and then click on the link again.

Am I using the `pageshow` logic wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I am attempting to do: AJAX this page into my mobile framework.

I understand this is a rather specific question, but hopefully there is a generic answer to this, as it seems to me that this could happen to any widget.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I can paste more code if that helps.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are binding to the `pageshow` event, the anonymous function will fire everytime you view the page. If you only want to call the code on the first view of the page then either bind to the `pagecreate/pageinit` events or check for the existence of the k3dCarousel in your `pageshow` code:

```
$("#page-about").live(
    "pageshow",
    function (event) {
        //check for the existence of HTML within the container element
        if ($('#k3dCarousel_portrait').html().length == 0) {
            $('#k3dCarousel_portrait').k3dCarousel();
        }
    }
);
```

Here is an explanation of all the jQuery Mobile specific events: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, your code has helped move me along. The reason I was using pageshow rather than pagecreate/init is that I couldn't seem to get any js to fire using those functions. I'm on rc2 so maybe i need to update...